# can JPA oneToOne relation defind child's FK in parent Table?

Tags: java, jpa

I have two table A and B, and they are OneToOne relationship.

Can I do like this ?

1. B table have the FK, like a_id, but A table doesn't have b_id.
2. when I get A entity, also get B entity. It means one way relationship. when I get B entity, I don't want it has A entity.

sorry for my english ability, thanks for answer

Comment: Yes, see Vlad Mihalcea's article on [the best way to map a @OneToOne relationship with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: The Hibernate documentation also have some examples: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived